"English speaking cafe" OR "English spoken cafe"?
There are some cafes where learners go to chat and improve their speaking skills by talking to people. In these cafes, only English is spoken and local language is not used, which is a good way of practicing.
And these cafes are called "English spoken cafe."
But this name sounds a bit incorrect to me. OK, it is a cafe where English is spoken, but using "English spoken + place" doesn't sound correct and natural to me. We wouldn't say "English spoken village/country/city", rather "English speaking village/country/city", would we?
So, I think the name should be "English speaking cafe", rather than "English spoken cafe". What do you think?

A cafe where only English is spoken is in the passive voice, when shortened becomes "an English [is] spoken café"

Both are fine. 'English speaking café' is very common. There is an 'English Spoken Café' in Istanbul (Turkey). They are also called 'English cafés', 'English only cafés', and 'English conversation cafés'.

Such cafes don't exist in the English speaking world, so there is no idiomatic expression for them.  I'd go with English language cafe (to distinguish it from a cafe that serves English style food, or a cafe with English speaking staff, as a convenience for tourists (rather than a place to practice speaking English)

https://www.bath.ac.uk/campaigns/language-cafe/

There are "Spoken English courses". In a similar way you can call them "Spoken English cafes" which means cafes which would improve your English.  What is a spoken English course?
English speaking courses cover a variety of topics essential for developing fluency and confidence in spoken English.

@JamesMathai, yes I would totally agree with "Spoken English cafes", but not with "English spoken cafes."

Google images English spoken here

These cafés you talk about are they real cafés i.e. coffee shops or courses run by schools and/or universities? Online I discovered many English speaking cafés are not in fact businesses but are evenings organised by and held in language schools or universities. Often free tea and coffee is included! :)

OP has commented

So, I think the name should be "English speaking cafe", rather than "English spoken cafe". What do you think?

I agree with OP that "English spoken cafes" is odd because we have "Spoken English course" but not "English spoken course".
"English speaking cafes" is definitely a better choice as it correctly conveys the function of such cafes.
I find it strange that a cafe whose purpose is to teach English should make such mistakes.
They can also choose  "Spoken English cafes" instead.

What is a spoken English course?
English speaking courses cover a variety of topics essential for developing fluency and confidence in spoken.
https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=english%20speaking




@Mari-LouA OP has explained it. But still it is felt that the proprietor of such cafes also need to be proficient in English.

Where did the OP say the owners of that cafe did not know how to speak English? I was once invited to go to this Italian bar run by Australians that  organized English speaking evenings in their bar/coffee shop. Owners remained behind the counter while customers (mostly ex-pats) sat chatting to each other at tables.  There was no teaching involved at all.

"I find it strange that a cafe whose purpose is to teach English should make such mistakes." That's not their purpose, not the real cafés anyway, the ones that are open to the general public and serve beverages, drinks, coffees, food etc. Once a week (or more ofen)  they will have these evenings where students, teachers and ex-pats can meet up and talk in English to one another. Sadly the initiative in the Italian bar I went to fizzled out because there weren't enough English-speaking people going there, and the Italian adult speakers who were studying English couldn't stay behind.

@Mari-LouA Sorry. As per your argument teaching is only carried out in school and there should be an instructor. The reason is given in the post. Other posts also mentioned the same. WHY NO DOWNVOTES THERE.? If you have a difference of opinion, give it as an answer.

TimR's answer is supposed to be a joke, it's sardonic but not wrong. So far  it has earned no upvotes. The answer by @fafafafa is written in quite poor English, which shouldn't be corrected (unlike typos or obvious unintentional errors IMO), and has two downvotes already, I can give it its third if you insist.

You didn't explain why "spoken English cafe" is preferable to "English spoken cafe". That's my downvote. If we are talking about real coffee shops (cafès) that sell coffee, snacks etc  they don't teach English. You say "Spoken English course" exist but not "English spoken course". In my experience they are called English language courses, English conversation classes/courses or even English speaking classes

@Mari-LouA I found  the term "English spoken cafes" is used only in Turkey. "English spoken here" is fine but not"English spoken cafes". Google search reveals that it is not idiomatic. In India it is either "English speaking course/cafes or Spoken English courses". If it is the other way in your location, you can answer. I had chosen "English speaking cafes" as my first choice..

In countries where English is the native language, cafes where English is spoken are called cafes. :-)

Very funny. How about where French is spoken? I find several French ones. The whole thing just bores me to tears. :)

That's a good question: "What is the grammar of 'it bores me to tears'?"

But there's one slight hitch to your logic. The cafés are just cafés but people could be speaking a number of different languages.

@Lambie  But English will surely be one of them, no?

English-speaking cafe is correct； the other wrong.
Note that gerund can be used to describe the function of sth.
A swimming pool is a pool for swimming.
But pool does not swim. We people swim in it.
Save you a Google: I checked it online for the term English-speaking country. The same case is for an English-speaking cafe.

"English spoken cafe" is not wrong.
